# Найти симметрическую разность двух файлов в python

Tags: python, файлы, сравнение

Здравствуйте, есть два файла. Но нужно не просто их сравнить, а в начале каждой выведенной отличающейся строки вывести название файла. Есть следующий код:

```
def diff():
with open('outputlog') as text_one:
with open('outputvec') as text_two:
    return set(text_one) ^ set(text_two)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('res', 'w') as result:
        for i in diff():
            result.write(i)
```

Допустим, вывело построчно
1111 222 3333
А хотелось бы outputlog - 1111 outputvec - 222 outputvec - 3333
Как это реализовать?
По сути дела, не важно, что должно быть перед выведенной строкой, мне главное знать, какая строка из какого файла пришла.
Эти файлы - таблицы значений сигналов(теоритическая и результаты моделирования)

Comment: А имя какого файла вы хотите выводить?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если в одном файле несколько строк "1111", а во втором их нет, этот код выведет всего одну "1111"?

Comment: > а во втором их нет, этот код выведет всего одну "1111"
да, так и нужно

Comment: >А имя какого файла вы хотите выводить
мне главное просто разграничить данные из разных файлов, мне не важно каким образом, можно просто а - 1111, б - 222, б - 3333

Comment: изложите, пожалуйста, в самом вопросе **все** ваши требования, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: @TransylvanianHunger, можно вычитать множества, в результате вычитания будут только те элементы первоначального множества, которых нет во втором множестве. Из вашего diff можно возвращать `return set(a)-set(b), set(b)-set(a)` (с именами ваших переменных). Тогда в первом элементе возвращенного кортежа будут только элементы, пришедшие из первого файла, во-втором - только элементы из второго файла. Чтобы получить элементы, присутствующие в обоих файлах - можно еще возвращать пересечение множеств через `^`, как было у вас в оригинале.

Comment: >если 1111 будет в первом файле в первой строке, а во втором файле - в 100-й строке, то эти строки будут считаться одинаковыми?
да, верно

Comment: @TransylvanianHunger, да, уже понял, дочитал ваш вопрос до конца)

Comment: можно [добавить метки на каждую строку перед тем как `set(a) ^ set(b)` вызывать](https://gist.github.com/zed/580cfd95ea44893e6396)

Comment: @jfs спасибо, но могли бы Вы пояснить, пожалуйста, последний кусок кода? и каким образом вызывать второй файл?

Comment: @TransylvanianHunger: какие конкретно конструкции не ясны? (можно [добавить в качестве комментария к моему ответу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/438296/23044))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TransylvanianHunger, вариант вашего ответа с небольшими улучшениями:

```
def diff(file1, file2):
    with open(file1) as text_one:
        with open(file2) as text_two:
            set1 = set(text_one)
            set2 = set(text_two)
            return set1-set2, set2-set1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('res', 'w') as result:
        diff12, diff21 = diff('outputlog', 'outputvec')
        for i in diff12:
            result.write('log mismatch: ' + i)
        for i in diff21:
            result.write('vec mismatch: ' + i)
```

В чем разница:

1. Одна функция diff вместо двух функционально практически идентичных, + имена файлов передаются через параметры (вдруг вы захотите сравнивать файлы с другими именами - не изменять же из-за этого код функции)
2. Каждый файл лога считывается только один раз (в оригинале - по одному разу в обеих функциях diff1, diff2)
3. set от каждого файла вычисляется только один раз (аналогично п.2)

Answer (score 2):

вот, таки воспользовался одним из советов и нашел простое решение:

```
def diff1():
    with open('outputlog') as text_one:
        with open('outputvec') as text_two:
            return set(text_one)-set(text_two)   
def diff2():
    with open('outputlog') as text_one:
        with open('outputvec') as text_two:
            return set(text_two)-set(text_one)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('res', 'w') as result:
        for i in diff1():
            result.write('log mismatch: ' + i)
        for i in diff2():
            result.write('vec mismatch: ' + i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить метки на каждую строку перед тем как `set(a) ^ set(b)` вызывать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Find symmetric difference of two files."""

class LabeledLine:
    def __init__(self, label, line):
        self.label = label
        self.line = line
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.line)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.line == other.line
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s: %s" % (self.label, self.line)

def labeled_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        return [LabeledLine(filename, line.rstrip('\n')) for line in file]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    a, b = [set(labeled_file(filename)) for filename in sys.argv[1:]]
    print("\n".join(map(str, a ^ b)))
```

Использование:

```
$ python symmetric-difference.py outputlog outputvec >res
```